# Stuck in developing a cooment box on the site

Tags: php, html, php-7

I am trying to develop a comment box on my website, but when I add `comment.php` file in

```
<form action="comment.php" method="POST"...
```

Then after filling the form when I click submit, the page completely shows me the `PHP` script on next page.

So how to solve this problem?

Do you guys have some idea??

Comment: This is the expected behavior. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Enable PHP in your server?

Comment: Have you configured your server correctly?

Comment: Please can you show us your code?

Comment: You either don't have PHP installed, or you haven't hooked it up to your Apache / NginX installation. In the case of Apache you should be looking for a `.so` module file in the conf somewhere, and uncomment it to activate. (restart web server)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need the package which allows PHP to be interpreted and executed on server side.

### Linux

Try to install the following package :

```
libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

### Windows

Check this SO answer, which is probably the best explanation you might find : [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

Good luck

Comment: On windows which software is needed to be installed?

Comment: If you're on windows, check the following answer on SO : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page